# How to place links in comments to other project files in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, comments

When I have a class, would be great if I could place some links in some comments above it. Examples: link to related unit tests, link to related integration tests, link to corresponding dto/domain class, etc.

This way I could ease the development process because the files which relate to each other would be easily browsable.

```
// Unit test are here ..\MyProject.UnitTests\MyNiceFeatureTests.cs
public class MyNiceFeatures {

}
```

In the above code I'd like to make the file link clickable, and on click I'd like Visual Studio to navigate to that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe helps- put in comments

```
 ///<see cref = "ConnectToApi" />
```

than you can navigate to specific method (in my example -ConnectToApi)

or ctr+click-able object in code is using "file:" prefix in comment to go to specific location

```
 //Unit tests are here file://d:/projects/tests/runfirsttest.cs
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, AFAIK for the first solution I have to add a reference to the project which contains the referenced class. As for the second one, I've tried it before but I'd prefer relative paths as the project root can be anywhere across different developer machines.

Comment: Yes, if it was possible to use relative path, it would be a nice feature. While something new is not created, ctrl+ C and ctrl+V keyboard keys will be at maximum use for navigation to related parts of project.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by using a "file:///" comment line like the following:

file:///C:/Users/User2/Documents/Some%20Documentation.pdf

Where the file is located at C:\Users\User2\Documents\Some Doucmnetation.pdf.  Note that if there are spaces in the path or filename you must escape those spaces like you would in HTML with %20.  It is not necessary prefix the file:/// text with // or enclose it in /* */.  This is with Visual Studio 2022 but I believe this works with versions even prior to Visual Studio 2017.